# is DRCSIM,for groovy?

Tags: gazebo, drcsim, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

there is a missing link between the ROS and GAZEBO-1.7  .

DRCSIM seems to be a way of fixing the link.

I am wondering, does DRCSIM supports groovy, which is the version I am using????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2855/is-drcsim,for-groovy?/) by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-05-20**:
Just to clarify, DRCSim is not "a missing link between the ROS and Gazebo". It is a software build on top of ROS and Gazebo to provide the features needed for the Darpa Robotics Challenge.

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-21**:
ok. got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Two versions of DRCSim are currently released in packages.osrfoundation.org:

1. ROS **fuerte** version for Ubuntu **precise**
2. ROS **groovy** version for Ubuntu **quantal**

Building from source you could get the others combinations easily, but they have not being released as packages in the OSRF repository.

If you are interested in building you own packages for theses other combinations, exists   [experimental code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/pull-request/17/initial-support-to-run-osrf-jenkins/diff) written for auto builing packages from a local machine (see launch debbuild README).

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0